# Error linking IRAF library relocation R_X86_64_32 against can not be used

Tags: fortran, linker-errors, gfortran, iraf

I'm trying to compile a program called DAOSPEC written in Fortran. It gives me the following error (among similar others):

> /usr/bin/ld: /home/osboxes/iraf/bin.linux64//libimfort.a(imakwc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC

See the full log [here](https://gitlab.com/evgenyneu/2018_summer_project_logbook/blob/master/a2019/a03/a02_star_reduction/installing_daospec/daospec_make_error.txt).

How do I fix it?

#### My Makefile

```
FCOMP = gfortran
FFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -fmax-errors=1 -O3 -march=native -ffast-math -funroll-loops

.SUFFIXES: .o .f
.f.o:
    $(FCOMP) -c $(FFLAGS) $<

default : daospec

daospec: daospec.o lnxsubs.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o bothsubs.o
    $(FCOMP) -o daospec daospec.o lnxsubs.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o bothsubs.o -L/usr/local/lib/ -lcfitsio -lplotsub -ldevices -lutils -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lX11 -L/home/YOUR_USERNAME/iraf/bin.linux64/ -limfort -lsys -lvops -L/home/YOUR_USERNAME/iraf/unix/bin.linux64/ -los -lf2c -lcurl 

clean:
    rm -rf daospec *.o
```

The same Makefile works on a different PC with Ubuntu 16.04 gfortran 5.4, but breaks on Ubuntu 18.04 gfortran 7.3. In both cases the IRAF library files are the same.

Comment: What is that IRAF library? The error message is quite clear, the library is not compiled with -fPIC, it is a static library. We should have duplicates around. This is not a Fortran or gfortran specific problem.

Comment: IRAF is an astronomical tool from http://iraf.noao.edu. The same Makefile works on a different PC with Ubuntu 16.04 gfortran 5.4.0, but breaks on Ubuntu 18.04 gfortran 7.3. In both cases the IRAF library files are the same.

Comment: Nevertheless, I feel it is natural to first try to follow the error message and only later try to compile different GCC instead. Especially considering it is a linker error so the difference may be in binutils, not in GCC.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: The error is reported by `/usr/bin/ld`, not by gfortran. And in your other question you are trying to install different gfortran to get rid of this error. I do not think that is a good think to start with. First follow what the error message suggests.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know that it's not gfortran, thanks. "First follow what the error message suggests." sorry what does it suggest?

Comment: It suggests to recompile the IRAF library with `-fPIC`. Or use such a (dynamic) version, if it is already available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem, with help from [Vladimir F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721644/vladimir-f). Ubuntu 18.04 uses PIE, position independent executables ([source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes)), and thus it requires libraries to be built with `-fPIC` option. The libraries in the [official IRAF distribution](http://iraf.noao.edu) that I used were not build with `-fPIC`, and that's what caused my errors.

Fortunately, one can now install IRAF libraries from the `iraf-dev` package on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt-get install iraf-dev
```

Alternatively, one can compile IRAF from  Github's [iraf-community/iraf](https://github.com/iraf-community/iraf) repository with `-fPIC` option.

Lastly, I modified the Makefile to use the new locations of IRAF library files: `/usr/lib/iraf/bin/` and `/usr/lib/iraf/unix/bin/`.

```
FCOMP = gfortran
FFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -fmax-errors=1 -O3 -march=native -ffast-math -funroll-loops

.SUFFIXES: .o .f
.f.o:
  $(FCOMP) -c $(FFLAGS) $<

default : daospec

daospec: daospec.o lnxsubs.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o bothsubs.o
  $(FCOMP) -o daospec daospec.o lnxsubs.o iosubs.o mathsubs.o bothsubs.o -L/usr/local/lib/ -lcfitsio -lplotsub -ldevices -lutils -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lX11 -L/usr/lib/iraf/bin/ -limfort -lsys -lvops -L/usr/lib/iraf/unix/bin/ -los -lf2c -lcurl

clean:
  rm -rf daospec *.o
```